# Question with tikzcd - Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I tried to do this, but I could not get it, any suggestions on how to make the arrows in the middle?

[image]

I try this

```
\begin{tikzcd}
C \arrow[bend left]{r}{F}
\arrow[bend right]{r}{H}
\arrow{r}{G}
& D
\end{tikzcd}
```

The manual of tikz-cd has this help, but i couldnt get the arrows on the center.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would be very helpful, if you could provide the code what you have reached so far. This makes it much easier for us (the helpers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this gets you started.

I don't have any kind of expertise with `tikz-cd`, actually first time I tried it.

### The output

[image]

### The output

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % for the mathscr
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  \mathscr{C} 
    \arrow[r, bend left=50, ""{below=-3pt,name=U}, "\mathcal{F}"{very near end, inner sep=1pt}]
    \arrow[r, ,"\mathcal{G}"{very near start, inner sep=1pt}, "" {below=-3pt,name=M}]
    \arrow[r, bend right=50, ""{below=-3pt,name=D}, "\mathcal{H}"{very near end,below}]
      & \mathscr{D}
  % the downwards arrows
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=M, "\alpha"]
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=M, to=D, "\beta"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a direct adaptation of the `tikz-cd` manual example posted by OP.